# X-Cart error after upgrade

Tags: php, x-cart

I am upgrading X-Cart on my home laptop with a developer license, so the live store is not impacted during the upgrade.  After upgrading from 4.4 - 4.4.3, I receive the following error when I try to reload the admin page:

```
> ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
> func_convert_trademark() (previously
> declared in
> ...\include\func\func.core.php:2597)
> in ...\include\func\func.core.php on
> line 2636
> 
> Call Stack
> # Time    Memory  Function    Location
> 1 0.2790  384688  {main}()    ..\home.php:0

> 2 0.3081  423888  require('...\admin\auth.php')   ..\home.php:48

> 3 0.3992  740952  require_once('...\init.php')    ..\auth.php:60
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue that may be specific for your X-Cart installation. You should post it to the developers of X-Cart to allow them investigate it and help you.

[updated] Or try to replace file xcart-dir\include\func\func.core.php with the same from distributive of 4.4.3. May be the issue is caused by problems with patch applying and this file (and may be some others also) was not correctly upgraded.